# show name only if you are logged in - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

How can I show the name only if you are logged in?

```
@if($user = Auth::user())
    {{ Auth::user()->name . " " . Auth::user()->last_name }} <i class="fe fe-check-circle ml-1 text-success tx-11"></i></h2>
@endif
```

I want to show on .blade.php

```
{{ Auth::user()->name . " " . Auth::user()->last_name }}
```

help pls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
@if (!Auth::guest()) 
    {{ Auth::user()->name . " " . Auth::user()->last_name }}
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do also like this

```
@if(auth()->check())
  {{ optional(auth()->user())->name . " " . optional(auth()->user())->last_name }}
@endif 

and if you have multiple guards on your application then you should use 

@if(auth('guard_name')->check())
  {{ optional(auth('guard_name')->user())->name . " " . optional(auth('guard_name')->user())->last_name }}
@endif
```

Hopefully, it will be work.

Answer (score 0):

See code below for best way to achieve this according to
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/blade

```
@auth

{{ Auth::user()->name . " " . Auth::user()->last_name }}        
// This is for authenticated user...

@endauth



@guest

{{ Auth::user()->name . " " . Auth::user()->last_name }}
// This is for guest (not authenticated)...

@endguest
```